# RightToLeft property on ListViewSubItem

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, right-to-left

I need to list items in latin and arabic languages. To do so I must display text in both left-to-right and right-to-left directions on a row in different subitems.

I know how to set `RightToLeft` property on a `ListView`, but how could I set this property on a single `SubItem`?

Comment: Does not make sense, that property should be set on the Form.  Arabic users prefer *everything* inverted, scrollbar is on the left for example.  If you need to control it for the occasional text value then you should use the [Unicode right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark).  Be sure to have your client look at your UI design before you do that.

Comment: Windows will lay out Arabic text correctly regardless the RightToLeft property. Maybe you want to set right alignment to these paragraphs, but such zigzag layout does not necessarily look better.

Comment: @HansPassant UI will stay left-to-right. It's just for occasional text; I will try Unicode right-to-left mark.

Comment: @HansPassant Right-to-left mark places punctuation on the left side of text. This is a good point but auto-ellipsis character is still on the right side.

Comment: @AlexCohn It's not possible to set right alignment on a single subitem; you must change `TextAlign` on `ColumnHeader`, but this doesn't fit my needs.